# The neuron that I'm trying to code in python using adaline learning is not working

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a really simple neuron of AND gate using adaline learning, but even after implementing the algorithms over many epochs, i cannot understand why I get the answer no where closer to the real answers.

```
x1 =[1,0,1,0];
x2 = [1,1,0,0];
o = [1,-1,-1,-1];
w0=0.2;
w1=0.2;
w2=0.2;
learningRate=0.2;
for j in range(0,200):
    for i in range(0,4):
        y=x1[i]*w1+x2[i]*w2+w0;

        w1+=learningRate*(o[i]-y)*x1[i];

        w2+=learningRate*(o[i]-y)*x2[i];
        w0+=learningRate*(o[i]-y);

print(w1)
print(w2);
a =int(input('give input A'));
b = int(input('give input B'));
print(w1*a+w2*b+w0);
```

After training, I expected the output to be really close to 1 when the inputs were 1 and the output to be really close to 0 in other inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no numerical solution to mentioned AND gate. This is why activation functions are used for the output of neurons. For this specific binary/logical case you just need a threshold and you are fine.